# Making use of ansible's dynamic kubernetes inventory in a playbook?

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, azure-aks

I'm trying to execute a few simple commands on a kubernetes pod in Azure. I've successfully done so with the localhost + pod-as-module-parameter syntax:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: kubectl
  collections:
    - kubernetes.core
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:
    - name: Get pod
      k8s_info:
        kind: Pod
        namespace: my-namespace
      register: pod_list
    - name: Run command
      k8s_exec:
        pod: "{{pod_list.resources[0].metadata.name}}"
        namespace: my_namespace
        command: "/bin/bash -c 'echo Hello world'"
```

However, I want to avoid the repetition of specifying pod and namespace for every kubernetes.core module call, as well as parsing the namespace explicitly in every playbook.

So I got the kubernetes dynamic inventory plugin to work, and can see the desired pod in a group `label_app_some-predictable-name`, as confirmed by output of `ansible-inventory`.

What I don't get is if at this point I should be able to run regular `command` module (I couldn't get that to work at all), or if I need to keep using `k8s_exec`, which still requires pod and namespace to be specified explicitly (albeit now I can refer to the guest facts populated by the inventory plugin), on top of now requiring `delegate_to: localhost`:

```
---
- name: Execute command
  hosts: label_app_some-predicatable-name
  connection: kubectl
  gather_facts: false
  collections:
    - kubernetes.core
  tasks:
  - name: Execute command via kubectl
    delegate_to: localhost
    k8s_exec:
      command: "/bin/sh -c 'echo Hello world'"
      pod: "{{ansible_kubectl_pod}}"
      namespace: "{{ansible_kubectl_namespace}}"
```

What am I missing? Is there a playbook example that makes use of the kubernetes dynamic inventory?

Comment: have you followed the steps from official Ansible documentation? `Now you need to supply the information about the Pod which will be created. Using definition parameter of the kubernetes.core.k8s module, you specify PodTemplate` https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/scenario_guides/kubernetes_scenarios/scenario_k8s_object.html

Comment: That one I haven't followed, because I'm not creating any k8s objects. The pods already exist, I'm just trying to make use of them.

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up the cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud provider? It is important to reproduce your problem.

Comment: What exactly is the _problem_? My question is **how** the inventory plugin is supposed to be used by playbooks, as the plugin docs page doesn't say :)

K8s versions are 1.21 on the client and 1.22 on the server.  This is on Azure's AKS, so I didn't set up the cluster. kubeconfig was generated by azure-cli (`az aks get-credentials ...`). Subsequently I use kubectl to limit context to a particular namespace (`kubectl config set-context ...`) which contains "my" pods (created _for_ me, not _by_ me), and ansible takes over from there.